# Why can not get query value in a label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, linq

I want to get a value from my database and set it as text of a label.

When I select something from a dropdown list, it passes a value which I consider as a type = 1

```
    protected void ddl_project_name_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     int type = Convert.ToInt16(ddl_project_name.SelectedValue);
     if (ddl_project_name.SelectedValue != "") //type =1
      {
        lbl_batch_status.Text = mydal.lbl_batch_status(type).ToString();
       }
      }

   public string lbl_batch_status( int type)
   {
        var result = from p in db.tbl_projects
                 where p.id == type
                 select p.project_status;
            return result.ToString();

}
```

But I just get the query. Why I don't get the result value?

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I catched what you mean anyway...`result` is an enumeration then `ToString()` won't join its values to a meaningful string. Change your code to:

```
public string lbl_batch_status( int type)
{
    var result = from p in db.tbl_projects
                 where p.id == type
                 select p.project_status;

    return String.Join(" ", result);
}
```

Here I assume that `project_status` is of type `string`, if it's not change with:

```
public string lbl_batch_status( int type)
{
    var result = from p in db.tbl_projects
                 where p.id == type && p.project_status != null
                 select p.project_status.ToString();

    return String.Join(" ", result);
}
```

Please note I assumed you need a list joined by space (change first `String.Join` parameter according to what you need). Consider also to use `First()` or `Single()` if you're sure you have only one element in the list (see MSDN).

Answer (score 0):

You can use your method as mentioned below:

```
public string lbl_batch_status( int type)
       {
            var result = db.tbl_projects
                         .Where(p => p.id == type)
                         .Select(p => p.project_status)
                         .FirstOrDefaulr();

            return result == null ? string.Empty : result;
     }
```